# is String or is Number function

Tags: qt

I'm actually working on a personal "Excel" for school.

When the value of my cell is a number (int), I want to add it in my listNumber (QList int). When the value of my cell is a String, I want to add it my listString.

These two lists then allow me to sort.

The problem is here :

```
QString test = text(i, j);
test.toInt(&ok);
if (ok == true) {
    listNumber.append(test.toInt());
    qSort(listNumber.begin(), listNumber.end());
}
```

ERROR     **`ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range" .`**

I think it's because it wants to "insert" a string in a list of integer.

Here my function "sort"

```
QList<QString> listString;
QList<int> listNumber;

bool ok;
QTableWidgetSelectionRange range = selectedRange();

for (int j = range.leftColumn(); j <= range.rightColumn(); ++j) {
    for (int i = range.topRow(); i <= range.bottomRow(); ++i) {
        QString test = text(i, j);
        test.toInt(&ok);
        if (ok == true) {
            listNumber.append(test.toInt());
            qSort(listNumber.begin(), listNumber.end());
        }
    }
}

if (listNumber.count() == 0) {
    QMessageBox test;
    test.setText("liste vide");
    test.exec();
}
else {
    int x = 0;
    for (int j = range.leftColumn(); j <= range.rightColumn(); ++j) {
        for (int i = range.topRow(); i <= range.bottomRow(); ++i) {

            Spreadsheet::setFormula(i, j, QString::number(listNumber.at(x)));
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: The problem is in `listNumber.at(x)` call. Your `x` value exceeds the size of the `listNumber` container. You have to make sure that it does not happen.

Comment: I m doing this condition : if(listNumber.count() = 0) -> then i do nothing, my x can't exceeds the size if there is  something in my list right ?

Comment: Oh, I understand now, you right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, qSort in Qt is deprecated and it is recommended not to use it:

> `QT_DEPRECATED_X("Use std::sort") inline void qSort(...`

You can use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::sort(listNumber.begin(), listNumber.end(), std::less<int>());

//or simply:
std::sort(listNumber.begin(), listNumber.end()); // using default comparison (operator <)
```

(But also you can simply call deprecated qSort:)

```
qSort(listNumber);
```